# change password from table

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to change password from the table and I am getting error. can anyone help me to get the solution?

Here is my data base class code:

```
public boolean change(String answer, String newpassword) {
    String sql = "UPDATE "+DATABASE_TABLE +" SET " + KEY_PASSWORD+ " = '"+newpassword+"' WHERE "+KEY_ANSWER+ " = "+answer;
    Cursor cur=db.rawQuery(sql, null);
    if (cur != null) {           
        if(cur.getCount() > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

here is my android code:

```
if(quest.change(answer, newpassword)){
    Intent login=new Intent(forgot.this, securityLogin.class);
    startActivity(login);
} else{
    Toast.makeText(forgot.this, "wrong answer",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

here is my logcat:

```
 08-27 13:23:52.735: E/AndroidRuntime(464): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 08-27 13:23:52.735: E/AndroidRuntime(464): java.lang.IllegalStateException: database not open
 08-27 13:23:52.735: E/AndroidRuntime(464):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1333)
 08-27 13:23:52.735: E/AndroidRuntime(464):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1315)
 08-27 13:23:52.735: E/AndroidRuntime(464):     at com.inovawe.inwp.securityDB.change(securityDB.java:163)
 08-27 13:23:52.735: E/AndroidRuntime(464):     at com.inovawe.inwp.forgot$1.onClick(forgot.java:36)
 08-27 13:23:52.735: E/AndroidRuntime(464):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
 08-27 13:23:52.735: E/AndroidRuntime(464):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
 08-27 13:23:52.735: E/AndroidRuntime(464):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
 08-27 13:23:52.735: E/AndroidRuntime(464):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
 08-27 13:23:52.735: E/AndroidRuntime(464):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 08-27 13:23:52.735: E/AndroidRuntime(464):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
 08-27 13:23:52.735: E/AndroidRuntime(464):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 08-27 13:23:52.735: E/AndroidRuntime(464):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
 08-27 13:23:52.735: E/AndroidRuntime(464):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
 08-27 13:23:52.735: E/AndroidRuntime(464):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
 08-27 13:23:52.735: E/AndroidRuntime(464):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

i got the answer, the code below is working

```
rawQuery("UPDATE "+DATABASE_TABLE +" SET " + KEY_PASSWORD+ " = '"+newpassword+"' WHERE answer=?", new String[]{answer});
```

Comment: before update open your database.

Comment: your **db** variable is NULL, in this line ` Cursor cur=db.rawQuery(sql, null);`

Answer (score 0):

```
"08-27 13:23:52.735: E/AndroidRuntime(464): java.lang.IllegalStateException: database not open"
```

Where in your code are you opening a connection to your database?

Answer (score 0):

You need to open your database connection before updating. Something like

```
db.Open();
```

or

```
if (!db.isOpen()) {
   db = getApplicationContext().openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_PATH, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE, null);
 }
```

And remember to close the connection after your work is done.

Answer (score 0):

you have previously closed your Database using `db.close()` please create just one instance of the Database and close it after all the transactions are completed.